# "3d Grid" Inside the Box in Graphics3D

Tags: grid, wolfram-mathematica, graphics3d

Please Consider :

```
cAxes = {{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}}, {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}}, {{0, 0,0}, {1, 0, 0}}};

Graphics3D[{Line /@ cAxes}, Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

Is it possible to have Grids inside the Box ? I guess "3D Grid"

Comment: You would have to do this as a separate set of graphics directives. `FaceGrids` applies to the box faces. Someone else is bound to type it out before I can.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a reworked version of what I believe Verbeia was attempting:

```
cAxes = {{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}}, {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}}, {{0, 0, 
     0}, {1, 0, 0}}};

a = Graphics3D[{Line /@ cAxes}, Boxed -> False];

b = Graphics3D[{
      GrayLevel[0.5],
      Table[Line /@ {{{x, y, 0}, {x, y, 1}},
                     {{x, 0, y}, {x, 1, y}},
                     {{0, x, y}, {1, x, y}}},
        {x, 0, 1, 0.25},
        {y, 0, 1, 0.25}
      ]
    }];

Show[a, b]
```

[image]

Comment: If you use coordinates like `Scaled[{x,y,0}]`, you get grid lines that will work for any plot range.  (Of course they may not line up with the axes.)